# VirtualEnv python imports not working

Tags: python, celery, virtualenv

I've recently been tearing my hear out over this trivial problem, nothing I found online has helped me so far. I am using virtualenv, my project structure :

```
myproj\
..bin
..tasks.py
..celery_app.py
..projapi
```

where importFolder is an API folder with a bunch of files in it. proj.py is my script that does all the work and contains imports like

```
sys.path.append("/abspath/to/projapi")
import projapi
```

I can source bin/activate and enter my virtualenv just fine, but when I go back a directory and run the celery worker:

```
 celery -A myproj worker --app=myproj.celery_app:app -l info
```

I'll get an import error for every folder in the myproj directory such as importerror for 'projapi'. It's as if the virtualenv is looking for all files in only the /bin dir (where as my proj is in myproj dir)

How can I fix this? I've tried appending all sorts of system and python paths, both in activate and in my tasks.py, but to no avail.

Comment: Just the guess: You are not using celery from inside the virtualenv. What does which celery tell you?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are using system wide celery.
Try to install it with pip within virtual env and repeat execution, that would fix your issue.

Also verify that each folder where you `.py` located contains `__init__.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the `celery` call itself?

```
celery -A celery_app worker -E -l INFO
```